# How can I automount VirtualBox shares in a non-default mountpoint?

Tags: server, virtualbox

I'm trying to automount VirtualBox Shared Folders in Ubuntu, the Sharenames are `*_DRIVE`, whereas * is D,E, etc. to then share them again via samba. If i

```
mount -t vboxsf D_DRIVE /media/shares/D
```

it works, but that's of course only until the next reboot.

So then I tried to mount them via `fstab`, which mounts them (as I see in '`sudo mount`') but the mountpoints remain empty. I tried adding `vboxsfv` and `vboxadd` in `/etc/modules/` but to no avail. I do, however, see that the `vboxservice` auto-mounts all shares to `/media/sf_*_DRIVE` and they are available. It's no problem to double mount a share though since I can manually mount them and they both work.

While I could share all `/media/sf_*_DRIVE`'s I'd like to just share `/media/shares/` which contains all mountpoints instead.

Comment: The `mount` command unfortunately only dumps the contents of `/etc/mtab`, and not the actual current kernel mount table which is seen via `/proc/mounts`.  The two do not necessarily match. Next time you see an empty mount point, do a `cat /proc/mounts` to see the real deal.

Comment: Can you show your `/etc/fstab` entries?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a kludge, and add the `mount -t vboxsf D_DRIVE /media/shares/D` to /etc/rc.local, as rc.local is run on each boot as **root**.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to get read & write permissions over that share, please do this

`mount -t vboxsf -o uid=<your uid>,gid=<Your gid> D_DRIVE /media/shares/D`

You can get your user id and group id from /etc/passwd file. This is how my user's entry looks like in my /etc/passwd file. First 1000 is my UID and the second 1000 is my GID.

`thefourtheye:x:1000:1000:thefourtheye,,,:/home/thefourtheye:/bin/bash`

If you dont want to execute the mount command each and every time you boot up, just add that command in /etc/rc.local file, as mentioned by @Yet Another User.